# Why is my ptrace failing?

Tags: c, ptrace

I am playing with ptrace. I have one simple program that loads up a shared library I built and then calls two functions in it. Both the shared library and the main program have a few calls to sleep() to give me time to attach.

When the program runs, I cat /proc/[pid]/maps to figure out where the shared object's memory is. I want to dump the contents of the loaded text section (or any other section of my choosing.

In the ptrace program, I attach, wait for a stop, and then attempt to PTRACE_PEEKDATA to read the memory. [Fixed by update below] The problem is, I am always getting an EIO error. Why is this happening? The process clearly exists, and if I ps it, I can see it in a 't' state-- being stopped by the trace.

Update: ESRCH error fixed (was missing parameters in ptrace call). I am now getting an EIO error instead whenever it tries to read. Why is this happening? The call to ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA...) seems correct and the memory addresses are on page aligned boundaries.

Main program (to be traced). Compile with -ldl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef int (*Add_t)(int, int);
typedef int (*Mul_t)(int, int);

#define LIB_PATH "./libmylib.so"

int main()
{
    void *pHandle = NULL;
    Mul_t pfnMultiply = NULL;
    Add_t pfnAdd = NULL;
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    int i=0;

    printf("My pid: %u\n", getpid());

    pHandle = dlopen(LIB_PATH, RTLD_NOW);

    if (pHandle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Did not find library!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pfnMultiply = dlsym(pHandle, "Mul");
    if (pfnMultiply == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not find multiply symbol");
        return -1;
    }

    pfnAdd = dlsym(pHandle, "Add");
    if (pfnAdd == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not find add symbol");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("add function address: %p, function pointer address: %x\n", pfnAdd, &pfnAdd);
    printf("mul function address: %p, function pointer address: %x\n", pfnMultiply, &pfnMultiply);

    printf("a + b = %d\n", pfnAdd(a, b));
    printf("a * b = %d\n", pfnMultiply(a, b));

    fflush(stdout);

    for (i=0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0) { printf("sleeping: %d of %d\n", i, 120); }
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Library. Compile with -shared -fPIC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile void *pFunc = 0xAAAAAAAA;
volatile void *pFunc2 = 0xBBBBBBBB;

int Add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("sleeping 200...\n");
    sleep(200);
    return a + b;
}

int Mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

Tracer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int pid = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned long long searchStart = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 16);
    long long searchEnd = strtoull(argv[3], NULL, 16);
    long long pos = searchStart;
    int status = 0;



    printf("Attaching to pid: %d\n", pid);

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("Ptrace attach failed. Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Attached\n");

    printf("Waiting for pid to stop\n");
    while (1)
    {
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
        {
            printf("Waitpid failed. Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            printf("stopped...\n");
            if (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGSTOP)
            {
                printf("Got SIGSTOP\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Did not get SIGSTOP");
                ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, WSTOPSIG(status));
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Process stopped\n");

    unsigned long long value = 0;

    printf("Looking at pos: %llx\n", pos);
    value = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, (void *)&pos, NULL);
    if (value = -1)
    { 
        printf("Error reading data\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Value: %llu\n", value);
    }

    for (pos; pos < searchEnd; pos++) 
    {
        long value = 0;
        errno = 0;
        value = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, (void *)&pos, NULL);

        if (errno != 0 && value == -1)
        {
            switch(errno)
            {
                case EBUSY:
                    printf("EBUSY\n");
                    break;
                case EFAULT:
                    printf("EFAULT\n");
                    break;
                case EINVAL:
                    printf("EINVAL\n");
                    break;
                case EIO:
                    printf("EIO\n");
                    break;
                case EPERM:
                    printf("EPERM\n");
                    break;
                case ESRCH:
                    printf("ESRCH\n");
                    break;
            }
            printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        if (value != 0 && value != 0xffffffffffffffff)
        {
            printf("%llx: %llx\n", pos, value);
        }
    }

    printf("done\n");

    sleep(800);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
user@machine:~/projects/scratch/x86$ ./call
My pid: 30776
add function address: 0x7f371292a805, function pointer address: e87569e8
mul function address: 0x7f371292a862, function pointer address: e87569e0
Me: 0x7f371292a805
sleeping 200...
a + b = 15
a * b = 50
sleeping: 0 of 120
sleeping: 10 of 120
sleeping: 20 of 120
sleeping: 30 of 120
sleeping: 40 of 120
sleeping: 50 of 120
sleeping: 60 of 120
sleeping: 70 of 120
sleeping: 80 of 120
sleeping: 90 of 120
sleeping: 100 of 120
sleeping: 110 of 120
done!

While that program is running...

user@machine:~/projects/scratch$ cat /proc/30776/maps | grep lib
7f371292a000-7f371292b000 r-xp 00000000 00:5c 14136507                   /home/user/projects/scratch/x86/libmylib.so
7f371292b000-7f3712b2a000 ---p 00001000 00:5c 14136507                   /home/user/projects/scratch/x86/libmylib.so
7f3712b2a000-7f3712b2b000 r--p 00000000 00:5c 14136507                   /home/user/projects/scratch/x86/libmylib.so
7f3712b2b000-7f3712b2c000 rw-p 00001000 00:5c 14136507                   /home/user/projects/scratch/x86/libmylib.so
7f3712b2c000-7f3712ce7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4200143                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f3712ce7000-7f3712ee7000 ---p 001bb000 08:01 4200143                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f3712ee7000-7f3712eeb000 r--p 001bb000 08:01 4200143                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f3712eeb000-7f3712eed000 rw-p 001bf000 08:01 4200143                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f3712ef2000-7f3712ef5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4200131                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f3712ef5000-7f37130f4000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4200131                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f37130f4000-7f37130f5000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4200131                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f37130f5000-7f37130f6000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4200131                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f37130f6000-7f3713119000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4200137                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f3713318000-7f3713319000 r--p 00022000 08:01 4200137                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f3713319000-7f371331a000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 4200137                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so


user@machine:~/projects/scratch$ ./trace 30776 0x7f371292a000 0x7f371292b000
Attaching to pid: 30776
Ptrace attach failed. Error: Operation not permitted
user@machine:~/projects/scratch$ sudo bash
root@machine:~/projects/scratch# ./trace 30776 0x7f371292a000 0x7f371292b000
Attaching to pid: 30776
Attached
Waiting for pid to stop
stopped...
Got SIGSTOP
Process stopped
Looking at pos: 7f371292a000
Value: 0
ESRCH
Error: No such process
done
```

Comment: "program have a few calls to sleep() to give me time to attach" - suggestion: instead of `sleep` for some arbitrary time which you then hope is enough to attach yet not long enough to be annoying, why don't you just put in a call of `raise(SIGSTOP)`? Then you application will stop at the point you want and you can attach a debugger (or whatever you like) and then send the program a `SIGCONT` to continue (`kill -CONT <pid>`) when you are ready..

Comment: Great question. The reason is because I want to apply this to arbitrary processes after I get done with this toy example. In those cases, I may not have the source to be able to add that call in.

Comment: Do you have proper permissions to `strace` your program or use `gdb`? The man page for `ptrace` indicates that `PTRACE_ATTACH` performs a check for `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS` access mode before attaching

Comment: Crap! Looks like I was missing a parameter in the ptrace call. The second parameter should be the pid, not the address. Now I am getting an EIO error, which is progress-- probably happening because I am not aligned on a word.

Comment: Looking at this further, I'm not sure why I'm getting EIO. The memory is mapped (smaps reports both rss and pss for the sections), and I am starting on a page aligned boundary. @Howard, I am able to strace the process.

Comment: I guess you should update the question with the current state of the problem.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I'd be interested in whether using `ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_flags);` makes any difference in attaching. Note this doesn't send a `SIGSTOP` to the process, but may allow you to actually attach given that you are running a kernel >= 3.4

Comment: I changed it to a PTRACE_SEIZE with PTRACE_O_SYSGOOD, and then sent a PTRACE_INTERRUPT. For some reason, it doesn't seem to get the interrupt. I see the "sleeping 200..." message from the library, but then my tracer never stops the process. The process eventually continues and then ends normally.

Comment: This is just conjecture, so take it with a grain of salt. I suspect that your tracee process is already suspended (via the sleep) before you are attaching. As an alternative try changing your tracer program to `fork()` and attach the child process before launching the tracee via `execve()`. That should eliminate the need for the `sleep()`

Comment: Agreed, this is probably the cause. I'm curious, though, how would one attach to a running process and examine memory if this doesn't work? My goal was to eventually try to grab on to existing processes rather than ones that I am starting myself.

Comment: I think it might be simply because you are using the `sleep()` command in your tracee program. For instance, you could have just as easily used the `cat` command with no parameters to test your attach/read/write/etc functionality with ptrace. When `cat` receives no arguments it simply waits for user input via `stdin`, and thus is blocked until EOF. If you don't like that option, try replacing your sleep call with something akin to `read(0, buffer, 1);`

Comment: Great test cases! I'll give cat a try first and report back :)